# Отобразить в случайном порядке слова без дубликатов

Tags: python

```
import random
WORDS=str(["слово","слово2","слово3","слово"])
word=random.choice(WORDS)
list=""
# while list in range(len(WORDS)):
#   word=random.choice(WORDS)
#   if word != list:
#       list+=word+" "
#
# print(list)
# input("\nНажмите клавишу для выхода")

# for i in WORDS:
#   if i != list
#       list+=i

while WORDS != "":
    word=str(random.choice(WORDS))
    if word != list:
        list+=word
        del WORDS[word]
print(list)
```

http://s020.radikal.ru/i722/1406/a7/52fb8723f829.png - скриншот

Уже почти все перепробовал, что вспомнил.
Вывод в этом примере должен быть: слово слово2 слово3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не понял из вашего вопроса.

Но если вам нужно отобразить в случайном порядке слова без дубликатов:

```
import random

words = ['word', 'word1', 'word2', 'word']
unique_words = list(set(words))
random.shuffle(unique_words)
print unique_words
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
В книге после каждой главы задачи.
Но random.shuffle еще не было пройдено из книги. И set не припомню. Может можно как-то без этого решить?

Comment: Конечно можно! Решайте.

Comment: как? Может подскажите без set и без shuffle?!

Comment: Пожалуйста:

    import random
    
    unique_words = []
    
    words = ['word', 'word1', 'word2', 'word']
    
    for word in words:
        if not word in unique_words:
            unique_words.append(word)
    
    
    def random_pop(src_list):
        random_index = random.randint(0, len(src_list) - 1)
        return src_list.pop(random_index)
    
    
    unique_words_count = len(unique_words)
    
    for i in xrange(unique_words_count):
        print random_pop(unique_words)

Comment: Если вдруг интересно, книга:
Майкл Доусон: python 3е издание. "Учимся python играючи".
Задача из 5 главы.
До random_pop,def,scr еще в этой книге инфа не дошла.